# C input and output redirection error?

Tags: c, redirect, input, output

I am encountering this weird message at the moment with my file.
I have a very basic C file that reads from a file and outputs upon request.
I am running the following command in Linux:

```
filename <filenametest.txt >filenameoutput
```

and it brings the following message:

```
filename: command not found
```

Any idea why it's not working?
Really frustrating.

Comment: Yes, 'filename' is the compiled file of 'filename.c'. I run "gcc -o filename filename.c".

Comment: It would be a security disaster if this worked! Imagine if I know someone who frequently types `lss` instead of `ls`. I could simply create an executable called `lss` that deletes all his files and induce him to change into the directory in which that executable lives. One typo on his part and *boom*.

Comment: Which part didn't you understand?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the part that windows' standard behavior is a disaster :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `filename` is the name of the executable generated on compiling your C code, maybe you should try using

`./filename < filename.txt > filenameoutput`.

Since `filename` is not in the search path by default.

Comment: "Since filename is not a built-in." No, it's just not in your search path. Note you're just guessing here, this question in its current state cannot really be answered...

Comment: In that case @dj31 must first compile his C code. I'm sorry, I just made an assumption here. Kind of new here, do I need to remove my answer since the question really isn't specific enough?

Comment: @ThePentium I wouldn't remove it right now, just correct the last sentence (in general, unix systems don't have "." / the current working directory in the search path by default). It *might* very well be the correct answer. Nevertheless, it's normally better to post an answer when you can be sure about it (and, gaining just a bit of reputation, you can request clarification in a comment to the question)

Comment: filename is the executable of of filename.c in my case.

Comment: You could explain PATH better but the nature of the unfound file is irrelevant so don't worry about the hypothetical. The file is unfound because it is not in the PATH. If it is not executable, that's a different error and a different question.

Comment: @dj31, in that case I'm sure that executing the aforementioned command should solve the issue.

Comment: I tried and it says: -bash: /filename: No such file or directory... but it doesn't make sense because the file is there 100%

Comment: there's a '.' before the '/' the complete command is `./filename < filename.txt > filenameoutput` try again, and if this doesn't work, please update your answer to include the steps you followed to compile your code.

Comment: another reason not to answer poorly asked questions like this ... you get to  explain every stupid `.` :D